# Spring Autowired Repository in Abstract Class

Tags: java, spring, rest, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract class that performs the common REST operations that are required, but can't work out if what I'm trying to do is possible. I've tried a number of approaches, but have stripped the code below right back to how it should work in my head

Classes updated as per suggestions below. Problem now is that the constructor in the concrete class isn't valid, as CustomerRepository isn't assignable to JpaRepository, though it extends that interface.

**AbstractRestController**

```
public abstract class AbstractRestController<T> {

  private final JpaRepository<T, Serializable> repository;

  public AbstractRestController(JpaRepository<T, Serializable> repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ResponseEntity<JsonResponseBody<T>> getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
    T restObj = repository.findOne(id);
    JsonResponseBody<T> response = new JsonResponseBody<>(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, restObj);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(response);
  }

  protected JpaRepository<T, Serializable> getRepository() {
    return repository;
  }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/customer")
public class CustomerController extends AbstractRestController<Customer> {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository){
        super(repository);
    } 
}
```

**CustomerRepository**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

}
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class, so AbstractRestController cannot be a `component`.

Comment: Good point, that was left over from me trying some other things, that's no longer in the implementation. I think the problem that I'm having is that I can't set the repository in the abstract class to be a CustomerRepository as the types aren't the same, despite CustomerRepository extending JpaRepository<T, Serializable> with T set to Customer, which I think highlights a misunderstanding I have with generics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, as @dino-tw mentions, you are trying to instantiate an abstract class with an undefined dependency.  You can absolutely have an abstract controller class, and even define request handling methods that will be inherited by all subclasses.  Try this instead:

```
public abstract class AbstractRestController<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    private final JpaRepository<T, ID> repository;  

    public AbstractRestController(JpaRepository<T, ID> repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JsonResponseBody<T>> getOne(@PathVariable ID id) {
        T restObj = repository.findOne(id);
        JsonResponseBody<T> response = new JsonResponseBody<>(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, restObj);      
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(response);
    }

    protected JpaRepository<T, ID> getRepository(){ return repository; }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/customer")
public class CustomerController extends AbstractRestController<Customer, Long> {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository){
        super(repository);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's taken a while to get a chance to try this out. This looks like it should work, however I must have something wrong with my CustomerRepository typing as I get the error "The constructor AbstractRestController<Customer>(CustomerRepository) is undefined" so it's not seeing CustomerRepository as assignable to JpaRepository<T, Serializable>

Comment: Can you append your updated code to the question?  It'll be easier to take a look than guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with the updated class, which were essentially your suggestion. It seems that **CustomerRepository** isn't assignable to **JpaRepository<T, Serializable>**

Comment: The actual repository parameterized type signature is `JpaRepository<T,ID extends Serializable>`, so maybe having it as `JpaRepository<T, Serializable>` is the source of the error.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I got a similar answer from a friend, I've edited your answer slightly to include Long as the implementation of Serializable. Thanks for your help!